# How can I concatinate content of two audios?

Tags: python, audio

I have an mp3 file, and I am also calling an API that returns audio. I want to concat mp3 file with audio content received from API call and send that binary to front end.

```
@app.get("/audio")
async def generate_audio():

summaries = await get_summaries()

audio_content = []

for summary in summaries:
    audio = await text_to_speech(summary)

    if audio.status_code == 200:
        audio_content.append(audio.content)

with open("news_jingle.mp3", "rb") as f:
    jingle = f.read()

content = jingle + b''.join(audio_content)

return Response(content=content, media_type="audio/mpeg")
```

But this approach is not working correctly. Audio in frontend stops after only playing jingle and does not play audio content at all. However, if I send only either audio_content or jingle as a response, it works fine. What could be the issue here.

I have tried using pydub and ffmpeg but these packages are not working.

Comment: Are you allowed to use other python modules to solve this?

Comment: yes, I can. For Pydub I am getting this error: 
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning) @MarceloPaco

Comment: Did you [`set up ffmpeg`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/#getting-ffmpeg-set-up)?